# Two "offtopic" flag reasons

Tags: support, flags, off-topic

The flagging window currently has two different possible reasons to flag a question as offtopic (seen by selecting flag -> "should be closed..." -> "offtopic because"):

1. This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.
2. **Blatantly off-topic** (this question has nothing to do with the software that powers the Stack Exchange network)

I've seen these reasons on MSE and on Area 51 Discussion zone, but not on [M]SE or [M]SU, so I'm not sure if this is a SE-wide default or just a coincidence.

What is the difference between these two reason, and when should which be used?

Comment: The *blatantly off-topic* flag is there for lower-rep users that cannot yet close for custom reasons. It is replaced with the *other* option for higher-reputation users. As such, I don't have the second option anymore.